# IndirectActorProducer class not exists within Akka libraries in play 2.1.1

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.1

I'm using play 2.1.1 and it uses akka 2.1 by default. I'm trying to find **IndirectActorProducer** class but it doesn't exist in akka-actor-2.1 jar. Do i need to add any new libraries for this? Also if i need any more akka libraries or different akka version, say 2.2, how can i configure with play 2.1.1 telling it not to use akka-actor-2.1.

Thanks.

Comment: I have manually replaced akka 2.2 jar in play local repository, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Akka (like most other libraries) is not binary compatible between different major versions, which means that you cannot choose which version you want to use with a specific play version. There is no play version which uses Akka 2.2.0 yet. In akka 2.1 the functionality of IndirectActorProducer is available via UntypedActorFactory (Java) or the by-name variant of Props.apply().